# In perl, is there a terse way to combine glob and printf?

Tags: perl, printf, glob

I want @list to contain all the filenames in $root_dir that match **YYYYMMDD**, where YYYYMMDD is 25 hours ago.

I try ...

```
my ($y, $m, $d) = (localtime(time - 25 * 60 * 60))[5,4,3]; 
my $pattern = sprintf('*%4d%02d%02d*',$y+1900,$m+1,$d);
print "The pattern is $pattern\n"; 
my @files = <$pattern>;
foreach (@files) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

... but instead of getting a list of files, I get *readline() on unopened filehandle*.

I know the <> operator can interpret variables, so <$y$m$d> would work during two-thirds of the days during the last three months of the year because those would be months and days that have two digits, but that is not robust.

Do I have to write ...

```
$m = sprintf('%02d',$m+1);  
$d = sprintf('%02d',$d+1);
my @files = <*$y$m$d*>;
```

... or is there something more concise?  Something like ...

```
# invalid code unless you want to produce the string "readline() on unopened filehandle" for some reason
my @files = <sprintf('*%4d%02d%02d*',$y+1900,$m+1,$d)>;
```

Comment: my @files = <${\ sprintf('*%d%02d%02d*', $y+1900,$m+1,$d) }>;

Comment: or <@{[ sprintf('*%d%02d%02d*', $y+1900,$m+1,$d) ]}>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
my @files = glob($pattern);
```

The `<...>` operator is way too overloaded already. Specifically, `<$...>` is taken as a filehandle.

Comment: Thanks for the elucidation about exactly how <...> is overloaded.

Answer (score 4):

`<>` can mean either `readline` or `glob` depending on how it's used. From perlop:

> If what the angle brackets contain is a simple scalar variable (e.g., `<$foo>`), 
>   then that variable contains the name of the filehandle to input from, or its 
>   typeglob, or a reference to the same [...]
>
> If what's within the angle brackets is neither a filehandle nor a simple scalar 
>   variable containing a filehandle name, typeglob, or typeglob reference, it is 
>   interpreted as a filename pattern to be globbed [...]
>
> *This distinction is determined on syntactic grounds alone.* [emphasis mine]

Since `$pattern` is a simple scalar it is interpreted as a handle and Perl attempts to do a `readline`. Call `glob` directly instead:

```
my @files = glob($pattern);
```

The overloading of `<>` can be a little confusing. It might help if you think of it as being a funny way of writing `iterator->next`. (Both `readline` and `glob` act like iterators in scalar context.)

Answer (score 3):

A bit superfluous, instead of all those shenanigans, you could use something from CPAN instead:

```
use File::Find::Rule;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->name( $pattern )->in( $root_dir );
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `File::Find::Rule` when a simple `glob` will do the job.  Your code searches all subdirectories of `$root_dir`, when the original code did not.

Comment: @cjm: Which you can easily disable with maybe ten extra characters, and get the added benefit of not having to deal with glob nuances.

Comment: list-context glob exactly meets the need here; the only problem was actually using glob, not readline.  Not sure I'd call that a nuance.